# Атрибуты QuerySet в Django 2.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Учусь Джанге. Возникла проблема удаления `Choice` из род.класса `Question`.

```
> from polls.models import Question, Choice

> Question.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Question: Hello, I am changed>]>

> q = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
> q.choice_set.all()
<QuerySet [<Choice: Not much>, <Choice: Not much>, <Choice: Not much>, 
<Choice: Not much>, <Choice: Not much>, <Choice: Just hacking again>]>

> temp = q.choice_set.filter(choice_text__startswith='Just hacking')
> temp
<QuerySet [<Choice: Just hacking again>]>

> temp.detele()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'detele'
```

Comment: Можете показать, каким образом у вас определены модели? А также, насколько стабильно это воспроизводится? Спасибо.

Comment: Не detele, а delete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо

```
temp.detele()
```

используйте

```
temp.delete()
```

(Ошибка в имени метода.)

Comment: Оооооох, это же надо так не заметить) Спасибо!